# In SQL I have created a temporary table in that I want to insert multiple data into a single row with comma separated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #Tempdata
(
    Account_Id varchar (max)
)

INSERT INTO #Tempdata 
VALUES ('3', '4', '5');
```

I want data to be in single as shown in above.

Comment: You mean `INSERT INTO #Tempdata VALUES ('3,4,5');`?

Comment: I think you are looking for `Insert into #Tempdata values ('3,4,5')`. `'3,4,5'` is one string that can be inserted into a single column of a single row. `'3','4','5'` is 3 strings that need to be inserted into 3 columns (or 3 rows).

Comment: *I want to insert multiple data into a single row with comma separated* - No, in a relational database you should *never* want that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is:

```
Create #Tempdata(Account_Id varchar (max))
Insert into #Tempdata(Account_Id) values ('3,4,5');
```

Which would produce the following result;

```
| Account_Id |
| :--------: |
| 3,4,5      |
```

Your example would result into inserting multiple columns
example if you had created your table like so:

```
Create table #Tempdata(column1 varchar (max), column2 varchar 
(max),column3 varchar (max)) 
Insert into #Tempdata(column1,column2,column3) values 
('3','4','5');
```

then your query would the following result:

```
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
|    1    |    2    |    3    |
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you're going to get a table set(multiple rows):

```
SELECT value
FROM #Tempdata
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Account_Id, ',');
```

If you want column-oriented, I mean one row and multiple columns per value, you should apply pivot on the result of the previous query.

Comment: Thank you now i got cleared with this @Farshid Shekari..